# Does CodeChef use the StackExchange engine?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I recently noticed a website, [discuss.codechef.com](http://discuss.codechef.com) with Q&A and competitions that is based in India. Instantly, I notice that it looks almost identical to an SE site:

[image: codechef questions]
[image: codechef user profile]

I am curious if this is a blatant knock-off site or if it uses the SE engine? I was unable to find any mentions of StackExchange in their About section. Also, SO has the codechef tag, [codechef](/questions/tagged/codechef), so it would be horrible on their part to simply copy the site's design...

Comment: You mean its not part of so already?

Comment: For a list of other Q&A engines similar to StackExchange, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%26A_software#Comparison_of_Q.26A_software

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The double diamonds (and the radio buttons near the search bar) kind of imply it's based on http://www.osqa.net/

Further, it says:  "Powered by OSQA" at the bottom.

Comment: It looks like OSQA is a knock off of SE...

Comment: Yup - was just doing to add that @Mr.Wizard :)

Comment: @AustinHenley Well - it's meant to be an OS alternative to the SE sites... It's not really actively supported though - the company that developed it appears to be trying to sell integrated help sites and stuff - plus it's quite buggy - I've had a play with it, but can't say I was overly impressed...

Comment: As you can see on their [list](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/12/what-sites-are-running-osqa) of websites that use OSQA, it is more than just an alternative. Several sites have "overflow" or "exchange" in the name.

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy ways to know if a site belongs to the Stack Exchange network.

1. Any genuine Stack Exchange site will have the [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/global-inbox/info) (aka "global inbox") on the top left on any page: (example for site with its own domain which is part of the network)

> [image]

2. Any genuine Stack Exchange site will appear in the ["All Sites" list](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

The site you mentioned fails both the above so it's not using the Stack Exchange engine and not part of the network.

Comment: I know it isn't part of the network. I was asking if it uses the engine. Previously, I have read that they sell the engine.

Comment: @Austin oh, thought you meant if it's genuine site. They don't "sell" the engine, they expose public API that let you fetch data from it, after getting a key, then use it under specific terms.

Comment: No, they sell (or sold) an enterprise edition of the engine. However, I read that those aren't public anyways so that can't be it either!

Comment: @AustinHenley you are right, but the "white label service" was discontinued soon after its introduction in 2009-2010, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History